# How to make AlpineJS "re-render" component after HTMX swap

Tags: django, htmx, alpine.js

I'm trying to integrate Django + AlpineJS + HTMX. All is going well, except when I try to swap some HTML that is already a part of a AlpineJS component.

If I swap the html the component renders correctly only after the second swap.

###### template

```
<div id="cart-row" x-data="{selectedOrderItem: {{item_id|default:'null'}} }">
    <div id="cart-holder">
        <table id="cart">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 10%">CANT</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%">TOTAL</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for item in items %}
                <tr 
                    id="product{{item.product.id}}" 
                    :class="{ selectedOrderItem: selectedOrderItem == {{item.id}} }"
                    @click="selectedOrderItem = {{item.id}};"
                >
                    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.product.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.get_price}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
        
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="right-menu">
        <div id="table-buttons" hx-swap-obb="true">
            {% for item in items %}
            <div class="" x-cloak x-show="selectedOrderItem == {{item.id}}">
                <button 
                    class="addButton"
                    hx-trigger="click" 
                    hx-target="#cart-row" 
                    hx-swap="outerHTML" 
                    hx-post="{% url 'add_to_cart' idOrder=order.id idProduct=item.product.id  %}?cartAction=1"
                > 
                    + {{item.id}}
                </button>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

For example, if I hit the add to cart button, the `#cart-row` div is swapped, but the `:class="{ selectedOrderItem: selectedOrderItem == {{item.id}} }"` binding only works the second time. It's like AlpineJS doesn't realize that the content has been swapped.

Is there any way that I can make the whole component "re-render / re-initialize"?
Or what is the right way to do that swap?

#### EDIT:

###### view

```
def add_to_cart(request, idOrder=None, idProduct=None):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            selectedOrderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order_id=idOrder, product_id=idProduct, defaults={'quantity': 1})
            if not created:
                selectedOrderItem.quantity += 1
                selectedOrderItem.save()

            items = OrderItem.objects.select_related().filter(order_id=idOrder)
            order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=idOrder)



            elements = []
            # CART
            elements.append(
                render_to_string(
                    'rfidapp/partials/cart_row.html', 
                    request=request, 
                    context={
                        "order": order,
                        "items": items,
                        "selectedOrderItem": selectedOrderItem.id
                    }
                )
            )

            #OOB SWAP TO UPDATE THE TOTAL AT THE BOTTOM LEFT
            elements.append(
                render_to_string('rfidapp/partials/order_total.html', request=request, context={"order": order})
            )

        return HttpResponse("\n".join(elements))
    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(f"{e}")
```

Comment: What do you mean by stating 'binding only works the second time'? Somehow it works after a second HTMX swap? That's strange. Could you share a minimal rendered partial HTML that returned by Django for swapping (you can copy it from the browser console's network tab)? Maybe the problem is on the backend. So sharing the view function could be also helpful.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The behavior is very strange, sometimes it renders correctly, sometimes not. Best I can do is a video: https://youtu.be/ng6t6JjRLP0 . The second time I added to cart, that row shoud've stayed green, but it doesn't/

Comment: I see. This kind of problem originates most likely from a backend logical error. Please share each relevant view function.

Comment: Thanks! Where do you define the `item_id` context variable at the backend?

Comment: It was just for a test. It was equal to `selectedOrderItem`.

Comment: I even tried to move x-data to an outer div that doesn't get swapped thinking that would keep the state. But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not including the one state data that this Alpine.js component is having (`selectedOrderItem`) in the HTMX request. So when HTMX swaps the whole component, it will lose the value of `selectedOrderItem` during the process. We need to send this variable to the backend and include it in the template. The easiest way to add additional data to the HTMX request is to use a hidden input element with `x-model` on it to sync data, and then use [`hx-include`](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-include/) to add it to the request. Put this anywhere inside the component:

```
<input type="hidden" name="selected_order_item" x-model="selectedOrderItem">
```

And modify the button:

```
<button 
    class="addButton"
    hx-trigger="click" 
    hx-target="#cart-row" 
    hx-swap="outerHTML"
    hx-include="[name='selected_order_item']" 
    hx-post="{% url 'add_to_cart' idOrder=order.id idProduct=item.product.id  %}?cartAction=1"
>
```

At the backend now we can access it in `request.POST`, e.g.:

```
context={
         "order": order,
         "items": items,
         "selectedOrderItem": request.POST.get("selected_order_item", "null")
}
```

After that in the `x-data` the selected order item will appear.

```
x-data="{selectedOrderItem: {{selectedOrderItem}} }"
```